# Adding my function into another?

Tags: javascript

I've added the first function superscriptDesignation to this code and now want to call it on the items in teamDesignations. Doing

```
return superscriptDesignation(teamDesignations);
```

gives me an error in the console that .replace is not defined. How can I add my function superscriptDesignation to the teamDesignations?

JS

```
  var superscriptDesignation = function(designation) {
        return designation.replace(/(®)/ig, "<sup>&reg;</sup>").replace(/(™)/ig, "<sup> &#153;</sup>");
    };
    var getTeamDesignations = function(profile) {
        //Designations for a single team member                                                                                                                               
        var teamDesignations = [];
        if (profile.team_members) {
            teamDesignations = _.chain(profile.team_members)
                .filter(_.compose(_.isArray, _.property('team_member_designations')))
                .map(_.property('team_member_designations'))
                .flatten()
                .uniq()
                .value();
        }
        return teamDesignations;
    };
```

Comment: when do you get this error?

Comment: It seems you are providing a non-string value to `superscriptDesignation` function. Or not providing it at all.

Comment: you are not passing argument in superscriptDesignation that's why it's complaining on .replace is not a function

Comment: `teamDesignations` is within the scope of `getTeamDesignations` and can not be accessed outside of `teamDesignations` function. (JS scoping) You should do like `superscriptDesignation(getTeamDesignations(whatEver))` Plus `teamDesignations` seems to be an array and arrays don't have a `replace` method.

Comment: how abaout `var superscriptDesignationList = getTeamDesignations(profileData).map(superscriptDesignation)` ?

Comment: You could use apply on that function and it will run but it's not going to work ass you want, i think you want it to run when you run getTeamDesignations?

Answer (score -1):

What this makes me think is that `teamDesignations` is not a string when it's being passed to `superScriptDesignations`. `.replace()` is only a method on the String prototype.

I'm not familiar with `.uniq()` and `.flatten()`, but is the result of that method chain a string? Either way, it's all in an `if` statement, so if that is not met `teamDesignations` could be an empty array when it's passed to `superScriptDesignation`.

You can either modify the `replace()` method in the first function to handle arrays, or put in some error handling to ensure that the parameter is a string. i.e:

```
  var superscriptDesignation = function(designation) {
    if(typeof(designation === 'string)) {
       //... do your stuff
    }
};
```